# Computed Column Equal to Letter

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to do something so simple, it's driving me nuts.  Especially since I remember doing it before.

I want to create a computed Column in a SQL Server table, and I want every entry in that column to be the letter Y.

Can someone please tell me what formula I need to type in the formula box in the properties pane of the computed column to pull that off?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Using T-SQL

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table_1](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Value] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [ComputedColumn]  AS ('Y')
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```

If you are using the GUI, then just type in `'Y'`

That said, if you want the value of `Y` in all rows, why do you need a computed column? Can you not just use a default value?